# jq: change multiple values within a select object

Tags: json, select, jq, edit

I have an array of JSON objects, and I am trying change the `name` and `version` on the object of a given `@type`, with the following input

```
[
 {
    "name": "oldname",
    "version": "oldversion",
    "@type": "Project"
 },
 {
    "name": "bomname",
    "version": "bomversion",
    "@type": "BOM"
 },
 {
    "name": "componentname",
    "version": "componentversion",
    "@type": "Component"
 }
]
```

I found many examples for changing a single value, and I can successfully do this by chaining multiple `select` statements together.

```
$ cat original.json | jq '[ .[] | (select(.["@type"] == "Project") | .name ) = "newname" | (select(.["@type"] == "Project") | .version ) = "newversion ] ' > renamed.json
```

But I was hoping I could condense this so I only have perform the `select` once to change both values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your approach:

```
[ .[]
  | if .["@type"] == "Project" 
    then .name = "newname" | .version  = "newversion" 
    else . end ]
```

or if you want to use `select`, you could write:

```
map( (select(.["@type"] == "Project") | .name = "newname" | .version  = "newversion" ) // .)
```

or more exotically:

```
(.[] | select(["@type"] == "Project"))
|= (.name = "newname" | .version  = "newversion" )
```

Comment: All three of these seem to work fine, I had been trying to make this work with map(), but I was unnecessarily constructing the output array, as in my original post example.  I also better understand the use of the alternative operator here, and the update assignment in the third example.

Answer (score 1):

Merge an object with the new values.

```
map(select(.["@type"] == "Project") * {name: "newname", version: "newversion"} // .)
```

Comment: This also seems to work, and it provides an example of the recursive merge, which I had never used before.